# Creating new oEmbed video provider / oEmbed displays in Wordpress posts but not in the editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, oembed, gutenberg-blocks

We are creating a service which hosts videos. Users upload videos to our website, and we provide embed codes for playback on their websites.

We have a number of users currently using Wordpress, so we figured we would create an [oEmbed service](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_add_provider) to let users easily copy/paste links into their posts.

We followed a [tutorial](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/api/oembed/), and and registered the following provider in wordpress via wp_oembed_add_provider in functions.php

```
wp_oembed_add_provider('https://vectorly.io/*', 'https://vectorly.io/wordpress/embed');
```

We set up an oEmbed service endpoint (https://vectorly.io/wordpress/embed?url=....), which returns the following json

```
{  
   "version":"1.0",
   "type":"video",
   "provider_name":"Vectorly",
   "provider_url":"https://vectorly.io/",
   "width":"600",
   "height":"340",
   "thumbnail_width":"600",
   "thumbnail_height":"340",
   "thumbnail_url":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/m.cdpn.io/screenshot-coming-soon-small.png",
   "title":"NVP DemoDay - Vectorly",
   "html":"<iframe src=\"https://api.vectorly.io/embed/demo/ba37b243-46c4-4f60-9a12-f6885b95c661\"  width=\"600\" height=\"340\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen  />"
}
```

Embedly seems to [validate the output](https://embed.ly/providers/validate/oembed?endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fvectorly.io%2Fwordpress%2Fembed&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvectorly.io%2Fembed%2F%23%2Fvideo%2Fba37b243-46c4-4f60-9a12-f6885b95c661)

Copying and pasting one of our links (https://vectorly.io/watch/ba37b243-46c4-4f60-9a12-f6885b95c661) into the Wordpress post editor does seem to successfully grab the oembed details

But the embed content editor block doesn't show a preview of the video
[image]

The actual published post looks fine though
[image]

It seems that the preview block is loading the iframe properly, but is just setting the width and height as 0 during the preview.

[image]

Looking at other non-whitelisted oembed providers, this issue doesn't seem to come up, so I think I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out for the life of me what it is.

Mucking around in various Wordpress files, I think that other oEmbed links (even from non-whitelisted 3rd parties) are doing something to trigger sizing of the preview Iframe in Javascript.

Any insight on this would be appreciated. Otherwise, we'll just forego oEmbed and stick with vanilla html embed codes

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles on this issue in the future:

You need to provide iframe close tags when you send oembed responses to wordpress

I.E. The following **does not** work

```
<iframe src="..." />
```

The following **does** work

```
<iframe src="..." ></iframe>
```

Adding a figure tag improves the result. See the fixed oEmbed output from our server

```
{  
   "version":"1.0",
   "type":"video",
   "provider_name":"Vectorly",
   "provider_url":"https://vectorly.io/",
   "width":"600",
   "height":"338",
   "thumbnail_width":"600",
   "thumbnail_height":"338",
   "thumbnail_url":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vv-raw-videos/ba37b243-46c4-4f60-9a12-f6885b95c661.png",
   "title":"NVP DemoDay - Vectorly",
   "html":"<figure><iframe src=\"https://api.vectorly.io/embed/demo/ba37b243-46c4-4f60-9a12-f6885b95c661\"  width=\"600\" height=\"338\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen  ></iframe></figure>"
}
```